# In Visual Studio code, how do I assign a single keyboard shortcut to multiple languages?

Tags: visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts, vscode-snippets

I couldn't find anybody asking how to do this: if I'm using typescript, I may want a keyboard shortcut for generating the boilerplate of an "if statement" like so:

```js
if (/* cursor starts here */) {
  /* selected text goes here */
}
```

But if I'm using another language, like Python, I would want a different "if statement":

```py
if /* cursor starts here */:
  /* selected text goes here */
```

[The official documentation explains](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets#_assign-keybindings-to-snippets) how to map a single keyboard shortcut to a single snippet. But as far as I could tell, it doesn't explain how to map a single keyboard shortcut to multiple snippets (each in a separate language file).

It felt like the documentation left enough clues to figure this out on my own:

```json
{
  "key": "cmd+k 1",
  "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",
  "when": "editorTextFocus",
  "args": {
    "langId": "csharp",
    "name": "myFavSnippet"
  }
}
```

I assumed this would be as easy as copying and pasting that in the keyboard shortcuts bindings file, and modifying the `langId` and `name` where appropriate. But this just seemed to call the snippet of the last matching entry in the file.

So, how do I assign a single shortcut to multiple snippets, depending on what language file I'm typing in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Though the documentation doesn't elaborate on these details](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets#_assign-keybindings-to-snippets), these fields are only used to scope *what snippet* to use when the keyboard is pressed:

```json
    "langId": "csharp",
    "name": "myFavSnippet"
```

It doesn't matter where you're typing, that's the snippet that'll be used.

To execute different snippets depending on the language, you must modify the `when`.  `"when": "editorTextFocus"` applies no matter what file you're in, as long as it has text focus. Trying to do two things at once is probably undefined.

Here's how you should change the [when clause](http://%20https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/when-clause-contexts) to do what you want:

```json
{
  "key": "cmd+k 1",
  "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",
  "when": "editorTextFocus && editorLangId == csharp",
  "args": {
    "langId": "csharp",
    "name": "myFavSnippet"
  }
},
{
  "key": "cmd+k 1",
  "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",
  "when": "editorTextFocus && editorLangId == typescript",
  "args": {
    "langId": "typescript",
    "name": "myFavSnippet"
  }
},
```

Also, keep in mind that if you give the snippet the same name in every snippet file, you don't need to include the `langId`.